# Activate IIS Hosted Workflow With MSMQ Using net.msmq Binding

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, workflow-foundation-4, was

I have successfully implemented a standard WCF service bound to MSMQ using the net.msmq binding.  I followed the instructions in a series of MSDN articles that are referenced through here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751490.aspx

The issue now is that I would like to use the WCF net.msmq binding to activate a WF4 service.  This has turned into a major frustration.  As soon as I deploy the workflow to IIS, the message box is drained of all messages.  However, no instances of the workflow are activated, and I do not see any trace information for WCF calls (I have troubleshooting log (trace) level configured in AppFabric).

In terms of troubleshooting / verification: I have configured and verified that WAS is configured, net.msmq binding is installed for the site, and net.msmq is enabled for the application.  Furthermore, the Net.MSQM Listener service is running.

I have not had much luck when Binging / Googling the issue.  There are similar questions online, but the answers are incomplete and the questions aren't related to IIS (w/ WAS) hosting.  Any help or suggestions you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I've included my full demo solution for anyone that is curious in seeing what is done thus far: http://www.bloggedbychris.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/ProofOfConcept.WfConvoy.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A document here describes how to configure IIS + WCF + WF4 + MSMQ combination:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+MicrosoftDownloadCenter+%28Microsoft+Download+Center%29&id=21245

Comment: The problem I see with this article is that, yes, it shows how to configure and set up the scenario, but I would have liked it to expand a bit on how it processes the message, or even if the server went down, where is the message now and how does it get picked back up when everything comes back.  I was able to create an app on my own that put entries in the Journal, but I want to emulate the "not so happy case"

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Server AppFabric makes this easy. You simply have to set the "Auto-Start" property and voilá!

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).